# Doubts with cross correlation in Python's statsmodels

Tags: statsmodels, cross-correlation

I have been trying to understand `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.ccf`, the cross correlation between two random vectors and I tried

```
sm.tsa.stattools.ccf(np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([1,2,3,4]), adjusted=False)
array([ 1.  ,  0.25, -0.3 , -0.45])
```

the lag 0 is 1, all right. But if I do

```
sm.tsa.stattools.ccf(np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([4,1,2,3]), adjusted=False)
array([-0.2 , -0.45, -0.3 ,  0.45])
```

why does the lag 0 here do not coincide with lag 1 in the first case (-0.2 != 0.25)? I tried displacing to the left to check if that was the case, but it didn't work, either:

```
sm.tsa.stattools.ccf(np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([2,3,4,1]), adjusted=False)
array([-0.2 ,  0.55,  0.1 , -0.15])
```

It is my understanding that cross correlation leave one series fixed and displaces the other, whether to the left or to the right. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I am interpreting incorrectly the definition of `ccf`. It is, following this link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1IyvwVWf6A), slightly different, with the displacement leaving some parts behind (ahead). To obtain the exact numbers you have to remove means and and normalize.